# C++ data validation not working properly and PDB error?

Tags: c++, validation, runtime-error, pdb-files

Evening everyone.

I have a program that is meant to have a ticket price and and have parent and child fundraisers to discount the ticket. The program is simple enough, but I'm also supposed to have data validation that makes sure the user only enters 20, 25, or 30 for ticket price. Otherwise, the program gives a chance to re-enter. However, when I run the program, it returns an error no matter what I enter, even if it's the right numbers. Also, if I happen to comment out the loop, it runs fine, but closes on it's own and says this:

```html
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Shaidi\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\High School Dance\Debug\High School Dance.exe', Symbols loaded.
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\ProgramData\Norton\{0C55C096-0F1D-4F28-AAA2-85EF591126E7}\NIS_20.2.0.19\Definitions\BASHDefs\20130412.001\UMEngx86.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
'High School Dance.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Symbols loaded.
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xa5c) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x304c) has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[10896] High School Dance.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
```

Can anyone help? Here is the program:

```html
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Prototypes
void studentTicket (void);
void parentFund(void);
void childFund(void);
void totalCosts(void);
void displayTotal (void);
void highestCost (void);
void process (void);

//Global Variables
double ticketPrice, candySold, magsSold, parentDiscount = 0, studentDiscount = 0,     schoolCost = 0;

int main(void)
{
    process();
    return 0;
}

void process(void){
    studentTicket();
    parentFund();
    childFund();
}

void studentTicket(void){
    double ticketPrice;
    cout << "How much does the ticket cost?" <<endl;
    cin >> ticketPrice;

    cout << endl;

    while (ticketPrice != 20 || ticketPrice != 25 || ticketPrice != 30){
        cout << "Invalid amount. A ticket can only cost $20, $25, or $30. Please re-enter a valid amount: " <<endl;
        cin >> ticketPrice;
    }

}

void parentFund(void){

    cout << "How many magazines did the parent sell?" <<endl;
    cin >> magsSold;

    if (magsSold >= 0 && magsSold <= 9){
        parentDiscount = 0;
    } else if (magsSold >= 10 && magsSold <= 15){
        parentDiscount = ticketPrice * .05;
    } else if (magsSold >= 16 && magsSold <= 30){
        parentDiscount = ticketPrice * .15;
    } else if (magsSold >= 31 && magsSold <= 49){
        parentDiscount = ticketPrice * .30;
    } else if (magsSold >= 50){
        parentDiscount = ticketPrice * .50;
    } else {
        cout << "The value entered in invalid." << endl;
    }
    cout <<endl;
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;
    totalCosts();
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;
}

void childFund(void){

    string studentName;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;

    cout << "Enter the student name: " <<endl;
    cin >> studentName;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many candies did " <<studentName << " sell?" <<endl;
    cin >> candySold;

    if (candySold > 50){
        studentDiscount = (candySold - 50) * .25;
        studentDiscount += candySold * 15;
    } else  if (candySold >= 1 && candySold <= 50){
        studentDiscount = candySold * .15;
    } else {
        cout << "The number entered is invalid. Please try again." <<endl;
    }
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;
    totalCosts();
    cout << "****************************************************************" <<endl;
}

void totalCosts (void){
    schoolCost = studentDiscount + parentDiscount;
    cout << "Parent Cost: " << ticketPrice - parentDiscount << endl;
    cout << "Student Cost: " << ticketPrice - studentDiscount << endl;
    cout << "School Cost: " << schoolCost << endl;

}
```

Comment: Never compare floating point for exact valuation; *ever*. Suggest you read [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), and anything from the `int` family for your values. If you need cents, treat your numbers as pennies (multiply y 100).

Comment: Not all DLL's have a PDB files distributed with them. The error is normal.

Comment: So then why does the program automatically close instead of asking to press a key like it usually does? Bear with me, I'm still a learning programmer.

Comment: @ShyGuy: Likely because you've written a console program but aren't running it from a console.

Comment: Nevermind on the previous comment. I got it resolved. Thanks a lot for everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

```
while (ticketPrice != 20 || ticketPrice != 25 || ticketPrice != 30){
    cout << "Invalid amount. A ticket can only cost $20, $25, or $30. Please re-enter a valid amount: " <<endl;
    cin >> ticketPrice;
}
```

Whatever the ticket price is, at least two of those clauses will be true. If it's 20, it's not 30. If it's 25, it's not 20. So at least two of those three will always be true, hence the OR clause as a whole will always be true. So your code is the same as:

```
while (true){
    cout << "Invalid amount. A ticket can only cost $20, $25, or $30. Please re-enter a valid amount: " <<endl;
    cin >> ticketPrice;
}
```

And clearly you can never exit this `while` loop.

Comment: So how would I do a data validation for the 3 values? Because I tried using if statements and it would reject the first entry but accept the second one. Regardless of what I entered.

Comment: Just change the `||` to `&&`. You wanted an AND clause, not an OR clause. You only want to loop if the ticket price is not 20 *AND* the ticket price is not 25 *AND* the ticket price is not 30.